# Deployment directory missing at Tomcat 7 by running from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat7

When I run `JSF` web application from `Eclipse IDE`, I cannot find directory(myjsfapp). I know that application will deploy at `<tomcat home>/webapps` directory.
That's why, I print out the `real-path` from my program as below.

```
Object context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String systemPath = ((ServletContext) context).getRealPath("/");
System.out.println(systemPath);
```

Real Path is

```
<my-workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myjsfapp\
```

Why `myjsfapp` don't deploy at `<tomcat home>/webapps`? How can I do to deploy at that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get one solution, change the path for `vm` argument at `Edit lunch configuration properties` of Eclipse.

```
-Dwtp.deploy="D:\dev\eclipse\hwak-framework\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps"
```

I also get another [reference](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway/wiki/Setting-Up-a-Tomcat-Server-in-Eclipse)